# Ceramic Capacitor whistle in DC-DC Converter

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply

I have designed a 24V Input, 5V and 30W output DC-DC converter (TPS40170) which is working fine under normal conditions.  This was approved with an evalboard.

But my load is being switched with a frequency between 100Hz-17kHz - I can hear an audible sound.

I first thought:

1. I have to change the capacitor package. I moved from 0805 to 1210 footprint. But this does not solve my problem.
2. I even increased the value of capacitor from 4x22µF (0805) to 3x47µF (1210). This did not solve the problem
3. Using the evalbord and making the same test, I am also getting the same sound.

I am now thinking to increase the frequency to more than 20kHz which on test is working, but my µC on the SPI-Bus will not handle this case.

What can I do to solve this problem  withhout changing my µC and also increase the frequency (more than 7kHz which is the maximum.)

Comment: If the sounds are generated from the capacitors, that's the Piezo electric effect, see: https://product.tdk.com/en/contact/faq/31_singing_capacitors_piezoelectric_effect.pdf  It can also be that inductor is causing the issue though.

Comment: At 5V output you can look into other types of capacitors with low ESR/ESL, such as polymer caps. That and smaller packages of MLCC in parallel (few nF) could solve the issue.

Comment: Also a way to check whether the noise is actually coming from the MLCC or the inductor you can use a metallic tweezer to lightly touch the parts. The tweezer sometimes will act as a tuning fork and make the noise way louder. So if it changes when you touch the MLCC and not the inductor then for sure its the cap. I'm not sure if this works all the time though.

Comment: Sounds like a useful trick, it doesn't matter if it doesn't work because it's not like you're investing a lot of time testing. :)

Comment: Is an added LC output filter an option?

Comment: adding LC filte could be a solution but this would affect the current slewrate and no space for it on the PCB.

Comment: Having read alll the proposition, the source of noise or auditible noise is coming for sure from Capacitor.  taking only few nF at output of the DCDC converter will not bring much because i need at least 88µF and space issue is also the deal. did somebody has already used noise reduction capacitor (e.g. Gj8 from murata) does it effectively reduce noise to 13dB? I am placing the components only on top layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the ceramic caps and they are definitely the source of the noise you can try adding a drop of hot glue over the offending piece(s). Ceramic caps seldom dissipate much power so should not affect the performance. And if it does, you can just peel it off.

Comment: I have already use many type of glue which does not give a solution. could you suggest one that you have used and being satisfied?

Comment: @Rompel Whatever you use it must be a soft gel trype of glue rather than hard setting. Also it would not necessarily be a total solution as there is still conduction through the PCB